# Dynamically use all SwiftUI Views included in a Swift Package in an App using this package

Tags: swift, swiftui, view

I have been creating SwiftUI Views in a Swift Package such as this one:

```
public struct DottedLoaderView: View {

@State private var isOn = false
let numOfDots: Int
let dotWidth: CGFloat
let dotsColor: Color

public init(numOfDots: Int, dotWidth: CGFloat, dotsColor: Color){
    self.numOfDots = numOfDots
    self.dotWidth = dotWidth
    self.dotsColor = dotsColor
}

public var body: some View {
    HStack{
        ForEach(0..<numOfDots){ i in
            DottedLoaderDotView(dotWidth: dotWidth, dotsColor: dotsColor, delay: Double(i) / 2)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make an application which will use this Package as a catalog of the Views I have implemented in the Package. I would like to display all the available Views from the package inside of a ListView in the catalog app to achieve a result similar to this:

[image]

The list row is calling the View struct from the Package. This works fine with a low amount of Views, however, I want to have hundreds of them in the future and would ideally want the app to dynamically display all the available Views and be able to iterate over them inside of a ForEach loop in the body. Is there any convenient approach that comes to mind on how to essentially "look through the Package and fetch all the Views available and have them as some variable ideally in a list?" so I can treat them as data to feed into a ForEach loop? I apologise if this is a really vague question.

Comment: Sounds like a problem that you can solve with code generation. I'd recommend trying [Sourcery](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery), it's one of the most popular tools for such things.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have installed and set it up. Seems like something I could use so thank you! Just wanted to ask where can you find a reference to the stencil language because I cannot find any good source.